# Android unable to access external storage

Tags: android, permissions

I have this code:

```
File rootsd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File[] imagelist = rootsd.listFiles(new FilenameFilter(){
public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
{
 return ((name.endsWith(".jpg"))||(name.endsWith(".png")));
}
});
```

And my permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Somehow the imagelist is null instead of empty. Can anyone help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: maybe you don't have any jpg on your harddrive...

Comment: Sorry, typo, what I get is null not empty. But from what I read, the only possible way to get null is no permission or file is not directory. I have no clue what I did wrong here

Answer (score 0):

move rootsd file upto the directory where images are present. you are just considering /mnt/sdcard path. point to the directory where images are in, like

```
File rootsd = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
            + File.separator + "imagesdirectory");
```

Comment: I did that and it give me the same problem, so I thought I make it simple and try to find the root of the problem first, even if no picture is in this directory, it should give me an empty array instead right